# Split JSON into multiple variables/ an array

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have this JSON String:

```
"[{"lat":"42.021631","lng":"-93.624239"},{"lat":"19.112049","lng":"72.870234"}]"
```

I need it in this format to be able to plot using Google Maps which uses this:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];
```

How do I get this in the format? I've received my string after using Papa Parse to import CSV and removed the quotes in the JSON text. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `JSON.parse` converts a JSON string to a javascript object

Comment: I get an error with that if I pass the result to Google Maps: ValueError: not an Array

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. Keys have to be surrounded with quotes.

Comment: I guess the problem is in you server-side. You need to stringify the json array before sending it.

Comment: Why did you remove the quotes in the JSON text?

Comment: If that's the actual response you get from the server (without the necessary quotes), then the problem is that whoever wrote that code generated the "JSON" by hand, by pasting strings together, instead of using a proper JSON serializer. This can be fixed either by adding the quotes in the hand-written code, or by using a JSON serializer for whatever language the server code is written in.

Comment: Making it a Valid JSON in question. I was removing the quotes but I guess I shouldn't do it as the first thing when I import data.

Comment: Response I get from Papa parse and then JSON.stringify is what I have mentioned in the edited question. I removed the quotes, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You string is not an json format, so you first translate it to json format.

```js
let str = "[{lat:42.021631,lng:-93.624239},{lat:19.112049,lng:72.870234}]";
let jsonStr = str.replace(/(lat|lng)/g, '"' + "$1" + '"');
let json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: @user3270763 my pleasure

Comment: Wait, so you are _removing_ the quotes from the JSON reply (as you mentioned in your other comment) and then _adding them back in?_ It sounds like the server was giving you perfectly valid JSON which you could have just left alone.

Comment: @MichaelGeary You may see the question before edit, It have no double quotes around the lat and lng.  I don't know when the edit added.

Comment: Ah, so is the updated JSON what you're actually getting from the server? The problem there is that the numeric values are coming in as strings, not numbers. The JSON response should have the property _names_ (`lat` and `lng`) quoted, but not the values. Because the values are quoted, they are strings and not numbers. If you can't get your server to properly generate these as numbers, then the solution is _not_ to strip out all the quotes, but instead to convert the values to numbers. Next comment will have details...

Comment: You can do that by simply putting a `+` in front of each of the values when you use it. For example, assume that you have one of your array elements (with `lat` and `lng` properties in a variable called `location`. Then you can use `new google.maps.LatLng( +location.lat, +location.lng )` to create a proper `LatLng` object with numeric values.

Comment: You should *definitely* not be using regular expressions for any of this. The best thing is to fix the server code to generate proper JSON with numeric values for `lat` and `lng`. But failing that, you can use `+` as mentioned above to convert the numeric strings to actual numbers.

Comment: How the + do the converting, is it implemented by the LatLng()?

Comment: I posted an answer that explains the `+` operator along with some other things.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.parse(<json string variable>)` will return a JS object that you can pass into google maps.

However: your JSON is not valid: `"[{lat:42.021631,lng:-93.624239},{lat:19.112049,lng:72.870234}]"`. The lat and lngs should be wrapped with double quotes.

Comment: Will throw an exception because that string is not a valid JSON

Comment: I used JSON.parse and it's giving me this error when I try to plot it : ValueError: not an Array

Comment: This is true. It's not valid JSON. The lat and lng need to be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse converts a JSON string to a javascript object.
If you leave the quotes in so it is valid JSON:

```
'[{"lat":42.021631,"lng":-93.624239},{"lat":19.112049,"lng":72.870234}]'
```

This will create a polyline:

```
var path = JSON.parse('[{"lat":42.021631,"lng":-93.624239},{"lat":19.112049,"lng":72.870234}]');
console.log(path);
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  map: map,
  path: path
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var path = JSON.parse('[{"lat":42.021631,"lng":-93.624239},{"lat":19.112049,"lng":72.870234}]');
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: path
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate code. It will be helpful if my code to add polylines dynamically doesnt work out!

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a valid JSON. If the string is from a **trusted source**, you could use eval.

```
var result = eval([{lat:42.021631,lng:-93.624239},{lat:19.112049,lng:72.870234}])
```

Will return

```
[Object, Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is eval.

```
var str = "[{lat:42.021631,lng:-93.624239},{lat:19.112049,lng:72.870234}]";
eval(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to keep the quotes ...

```
x = "[{lat:42.021631,lng:-93.624239},{lat:19.112049,lng:0},{lat:42.112049,lng:0}]".split("},{");
var regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;

flightPlanCoordinates = [];
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  coords = x[i].match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });

  if (coords.length === 2) {
        flightPlanCoordinates.push({ "lat": coords[0], "lng": coords[1] });
  }
}

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates);
```

Kris Roofe's answer is quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here, given the latest update to your question, is that the `lat` and `lng` values in your JSON data are strings instead of numbers.

In other words, where your JSON data looks like this (whitespace added for clarity):

```
[
    { "lat": "42.021631", "lng": "-93.624239" },
    { "lat": "19.112049", "lng": "72.870234" }
]
```

it should look like this:

```
[
    { "lat": 42.021631, "lng": -93.624239 },
    { "lat": 19.112049, "lng": 72.870234 }
]
```

The best way to fix this is to change your server code to generate that second format instead of the first one. I can't give specifics because I don't know what server language or libraries you are using. But if you can get the server to generate the `lat` and `lng` values as the numbers they should be instead of strings, everything will get easier.

If that can't be done, the solution is *not* to be mucking around with the JSON text, stripping out quotes or adding them back in with regular expressions. That is just creating a mess that you don't need and doesn't help you.

Instead, simply convert the `lat` and `lng` values to numbers where you need to.

For example, if you have the first element of your JSON array in a variable called `location`, you may be trying to create a `LatLng` object from it like this:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( location.lat, location.lng );
```

That may not work, because `location.lat` and `location.lng` are strings, not numbers. But you can easily convert them to numbers:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( +location.lat, +location.lng );
```

There are several ways to convert a string to a number, but the unary `+` operator is the most succinct.

How does the `+` operator work? It isn't specific to Google Maps or the `LatLng` object or anything like that. It's simply a JavaScript operator. If you apply the `+` operator to something that is already a number, it just leaves it alone. But if you apply `+` to a *string*, it converts it to a number.

Alternatively, you could use the `parseFloat` function:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(location.lat),
    parseFloat(location.lng)
);
```

There's nothing wrong with that if you find it more clear, but try the `+` operator: once you get used to it, you may find you like it.

Again, though, the best solution is to fix the server code to generate proper JSON numbers as illustrated above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep the quotes in the JSON text and run this line:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = JSON.parse('[{"lat":"42.021631","lng":"-93.624239"},{"lat":"19.112049","lng":"72.870234"}]')
```

Comment: I get ValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number